# Spring Cloud Zuul-Gateway mapping with Config-Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I'm developing a spring-microservice architecture with following modules (see the architecture diagram below):

- Configuration-server
- Eureka-Server
- Zuul Api Gateway
- User-api(Config-Server-Client, Eureka-Client)
- Stats-api(Config-Server-Client, Eureka-Client)
- Auth-Service (in-progress/out of context)

**It's is more of a configuration approach rather than a bug**. So far everything is running fine.
For most of the configurations of core-apis, I'm loading them from config-Server.

What should be the actual or recommended way if we use `config-server` with `Api-Gateway`?
Would it be good to map(load from) the configuration of Zuul-Gateway to my Config-Server as with other core apis like User-Api and Stats-Api.

And if I did so what should be the order of starting the applications?
Like:
1. Start the Config-Server
2. Eureka Server
3. Zuul Gateway
4. Core-Apis

Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have build a similar architecture for testing purpose. You can find in the link below:
https://github.com/rshtishi/payroll

The order I use to start the services is like below:

1. Configuration Server (Spring Cloud Config Server) is always the first start. Here are the configuration for all the services.
2. Eureka Server, is responsible for registering all services.

After starting the service above, you can start whatever you wish api-services or zuul gateway server. Zuul gateway server will access the api services through eureka. So it doesn't matter the order.